# Android: Cannot create a list with some items expandable and some items not

Tags: android

How can I create a list with some items expandable and some items like a normal listView. I have got a normal listView working but cannot integrate expandable list items.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class Home extends ListActivity{


String[] items={"John", "Tom", "William", "Jake"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.home, items));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need override the [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) methods. This means your going to have to write your own [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) class.